# Jquery : animate image on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to animate an image in specific  part of  page when page is scrolled to that area. Animation should be like this: when page loads that image is invisible and as we scroll down that image fadesIn and moves from right to left 100px  .

this is what i did to get scroll position

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.myimages').hide();
 var target = $(".img-div").offset().top; 
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >=target)
   {                 
     $('.myimages').fadeIn();
   }
   }, 250);
  });
```

now instead of image fading in what i need to animate it as per above mentioned criteria  i tried something like this

```
$('.myimages').animate({right:'100'}, 200);
```

but this did not work please help me with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of firing a `setInterval` every few seconds, you can bind it to the `window`'s `scroll` event.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target)
    $('.myimages').fadeIn();
});
```

To animate the `right` and other similar CSS properties, you need to set the `.image`'s position to be something else than `static`.

```
$('.myimages').animate({
  right: 100
}, 200);
```

So, you need this in CSS:

```
.myimages {position: absolute;}
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("img").hide();
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("img").scrollTop())
      $("img").show().addClass("bounceInRight");
  });
});
```

```css
.animated { 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
  animation-duration: 1s; 
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
  animation-fill-mode: both; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInRight { 
  0% { 
    opacity: 0; 
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2000px); 
  } 
  60% { 
    opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px); 
  } 
  80% { 
    -webkit-transform: translateX(10px); 
  } 
  100% { 
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0); 
  } 
} 

@keyframes bounceInRight { 
  0% { 
    opacity: 0; 
    transform: translateX(2000px); 
  } 
  60% { 
    opacity: 1; 
    transform: translateX(-30px); 
  } 
  80% { 
    transform: translateX(10px); 
  } 
  100% { 
    transform: translateX(0); 
  } 
} 

.bounceInRight { 
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInRight; 
  animation-name: bounceInRight; 
}

img {max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<h1>Animation</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, unde amet a repellat tempora ipsum! Maiores minima sapiente blanditiis, asperiores necessitatibus corporis incidunt! Ex, praesentium aliquam omnis dicta quo. Quisquam.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero eius eligendi praesentium doloremque voluptatibus, vero sed aspernatur officia eum repellat unde dolore ut eaque esse, officiis natus harum vel eos.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta atque beatae temporibus et officiis enim, rem facere! Voluptatibus adipisci, odit in necessitatibus explicabo eveniet culpa. Nisi praesentium quasi error ducimus!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus autem facere ipsa ratione excepturi praesentium. Reiciendis aut praesentium earum laboriosam, architecto quasi error, corporis, nesciunt maxime distinctio quo nisi debitis.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati eos, consequatur voluptatibus harum deserunt! Fugit voluptatem veniam atque, odio aut qui iste laudantium, nemo error vero natus eaque unde sunt!</p>
<p><img src="https://assets.keycdn.com/img/cdn-network.svg" alt="" class="animated" /></p>
```

Comment: ok i will but if you please help  me to code animation part ,

Comment: @Sikander Please correct my name. It is Praveen. Sure I can help you. What exactly you wanna try?

Comment: at first image is not visible and when page scrolled to image's section then it comes from extreme right and takes its position which is 100px from right side ,  should i set something like this $('.myimages '),parent().css({position:reative}; and then $('.myimages ').animate({position:'absolute', right:100 }, slow);  or what ?

Comment: @Sikander Give me a min. I will create a fiddle for you.

Comment: Thats perfect Praveen Kumar .. ! thank you very much for such detailed reply